# How to add a comment in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, comments, code-standards

I have a some piece of code like this. How can I add comments? It has both HTML and PHP combined code.

```
<?php / echo zen_draw_form('currencies', zen_href_link(basename(ereg_replace('.php', '', $PHP_SELF)), '', $request_type, false), 'get'); ?>

    <div>
        <span class="label"><?php echo BOX_HEADING_CURRENCIES;?>: &nbsp;</span>

        <?php
            if (isset($currencies) && is_object($currencies)) {

                reset($currencies->currencies);
                $currencies_array = array();
                while (list($key, $value) = each($currencies->currencies)) {
                    $currencies_array[] = array('id' => $key, 'text' => $value['title']);
                }

                $hidden_get_variables = '';
                reset($_GET);
                while (list($key, $value) = each($_GET)) {
                    if (($key != 'currency') &&
                        ($key != zen_session_name()) &&
                        ($key != 'x') &&
                        ($key != 'y')) {

                        $hidden_get_variables .= zen_draw_hidden_field($key, $value);
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
        <?php echo zen_draw_pull_down_menu('currency', $currencies_array, $_SESSION['currency'], 'class="select" onchange="this.form.submit();"') . $hidden_get_variables . zen_hide_session_id()?>
    </div>
</form> */
```

Comment: And why is this tagged [ajax]

Comment: <!-- comment --> for html and /* comment */ for php and what is your question?

Comment: Please have a look [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: I think that his issue is that he has mixed PHP and HTML and he want to comment out a mixed part of PHP and HTML

Comment: Isn't it missing a "`*`" near "`<?php /`"?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    // PHP comment for one line ?>

    <?php
        /*    This is
              a PHP comment for
              block */
    ?>
```

For HTML:

```
<!-- Comment for HTML code
<a href="#">test></a> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the PHP code inside the PHP tags like this:

```
<?php
    // This is a PHP comment line

    /*
        This is
        a PHP comment
        block
    */
?>
```

It doesn't matter if you have everything commented out inside the php tags.

Comment: PHP allows for Perl style comments also, like `# my comment`

Answer (score 0):

You can use comment's like this,

```
<!-- Comment for HTML code
<form>
    <div>
        <?php /* Comment for PHP code */ ?>
    </div>
</form> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different comment styles - one for PHP and one for HTML.

See the example below.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <!--
        <body>
            <?php

            /* echo 'Hello, World!'; */
            ?>
        </body>

    </head> -->

</html>
```

Comment: With or without the comments, this is not valid HTML (without comments, the HTML `body` tag is inside the HTML `head` tag).